# Проблема выполнения SQL запроса

Tags: c#, sql

Вопрос в том как выполнить большой SQL запрос. я пробовал через вставку запроса в cs фаил и выполнять его вот таким кодом:

```
string connectionString = String.Empty;
connectionString = "строка подключения";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = @"Большой запрос на 500 строк";
try {
  connection.Open();
  SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
  while (reader.Read()) {}
  read.Close();
  connection.Close;
} и тд
```

Вообщем возникла проблема, в том что вставлялись спец символы типа /n/t/r и 
из-за этого запрос не выполнялся. Искал варианты разрешения проблемы - не нашел.

Попробовал создать текстовый фаил и выполнить его командой sqlcmd
Все получилось, но возникла другая проблема, при создании экзешника, фаил запроса должен быть в той же директории что и установщик. Мне нужно чтобы был один установщик, который мог бы выполнить запрос. 
 При использовании 1 способа пробовал менять кодировки, записывать в одну строку без пробелов(это рили жесть), использовал разные методы выполнения запроса, даже выписал каждую строку запроса в виде

```
@"CREATE TABLE [dbo].[RUSDevices] (" + 
  "[id] ... ," + 
  "CREATE PROCEDURE [такая то]" + ...
```

(каждую строку переносил и добавлял в конце "+". занятие честно говоря не из лучших)  - это не помогло. 
Во втором способе пробовал добавлять фаил в ресурсы но не понял как его можно от туда выполнить. Для выполнения использовал след код:

```
  System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
  System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new 
     System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();
  startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowsStyle.Hidden;
  startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
  startInfo.Arguments = "/C sqlcms и тд";
  process.StartInfo = startInfo;
  process.Start();
  process.Close();
```

Помогите плиз, рили уже долго ищу решение и не нахожу((
Я новичок в программировании, не судите строго.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61662/discussion-on-question-by-eugeny-filippov---sql-).

Answer (score 1):

> вставлялись спец символы типа /n/t/r и из-за этого запрос не
>   выполнялся

А Вы уверены, что из-за этого? Может причина в самом запросе? У меня, например, этот код без проблем выполняется:

```
var connstr = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connstr.DataSource = "localhost";
connstr.InitialCatalog = "TEST";
connstr.UserID = "sa";
connstr.Password = "9";
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connstr.ToString()))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText =
            @"SELECT  D.ID, D.dName, D.dDescription, D.dQuery, D.dType, L.ID AS Expr1, L.formID, L.layName, 
            L.layout, L.isdef, P.ID AS Expr2, P.formID AS Expr3, P.paramName, P.pDescription, P.paramType, 
            P.pQuery, P.paramFormatStr
            FROM  DynForms AS D INNER JOIN
            DynFormsLayout AS L ON L.formID = D.ID INNER JOIN
            DynFormsParams AS P ON P.formID = D.ID";
        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Хотя эти символы "вставляются" и у меня (см. скрин).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хорошо, понял)) значит вопрос в другом.